# Bootstrap v5.0 offcanvas call modal and offcanvas backdrop at same time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am dealing with bootstrap v5.0 offcanvas. Everything was a success until one step.

When i click on offcanvas button, my page seems to be calling both offcanvas-backdrop and modal-backdrop div at the same time

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
<div class="offcanvas-backdrop fade show" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
```

What is the issue that caused this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm getting the same issue but when using Bootstrap's classes:

the official example from Bootstrap's documentation is showing a faded offcanvas...

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasBottomLabel">Offcanvas bottom</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body small">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```